# I want to create multiple tables with the same composite primary key without data redundancy in mysql. How can I achieve this?

Tags: mysql, foreign-keys, composite-primary-key, redundancy

I am using mysql to create a database.

I have one base table named GP, with its Primary Key a composite Primary Key(SAT_ID, DATE).
I want to create multiple tables with the same Primary Key (`SAT_ID`,`DATE`), but would like to avoid data redundancy.

Is there a way to create a Primary Key for the children tables (for example `ID INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT`) that references the composite Primary Key (`SAT_ID`,`DATE`), so that I can avoid having the same composite Primary Key (`SAT_ID`,`DATE`) in every other table ?

I know the question can seem silly but there is something I don't understand about composite keys and data redundancy.

Thanks

Comment: Is there a way to create a Primary Key f... no there isn't, but you might consider junction r=tables

Comment: You could modify your GP table to have an autoincrement `ID` as PK and an unique index on `(SAT_ID, DATE)`, then you can use `ID` as foreign key in your other tables

Comment: Thanks @Pepper, that should do the trick.

Answer (score 1):

@pepper's solution (suggested in the comments) works just fine:

> You could modify your GP table to have an autoincrement `ID` as PK and
> an unique index on `(SAT_ID, DATE)`, then you can use `ID` as foreign
> key in your other tables